# Diferencias entre los selectores :root y html

Tags: html, css

No me queda muy claro cuándo usar un selector u otro o si tienen realmente una diferencia clara, ¿Los uso según crea conveniente? O según algún uso específico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo con la especificación<sup>1</sup>

La pseudoclase **`root`**, representa la raíz de un documento, dentro de un documento HTML representa a la etiqueta **`<html></html>`**

**Ejemplo 1**

Puedes observar como con dicha pseudoclase sin apuntar de forma explícita a la etiqueta HTML, el color de fondo se aplicó al documento completo; es decir busco el elemento de mas alto nivel

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo 1</title>
      <style>
        :root{
          background: tomato;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Ejemplo 2**

Observa como basándonos en el tema de especificidad, en el siguiente snnipet aunque por cascada el color red de la etiqueta html se debería aplicar, se ignora y se mantiene el color tomato de la pseudoclase **`:root`** por tener un nivel de especificidad mayor

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo 2</title>
      <style>
        :root{
          background: tomato;
        }
        html{
          background: red;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Lo anterior lo puedes comprobar en la siguiente imagen, donde observas como el navegador cancela el estilo de la etiqueta **`html`** y solo mantiene la de **`root`** por lo ya antes expuesto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se menciona el tema de la especificidad, por que es el método por el cual el navegador determina que estilos tienen mayor peso o relevancia de aplicación por sobre otros; es decir como podemos leer en la doc de Mozilla Developer<sup>2</sup>; el orden es así:

```
Elemento                              Nivel
etiquetas                               0
clases, de atributos y pesudoclases     1
selectores de id                        2
```

Entonces como puedes notar es mas específico usar en este caso la *pseudoclase* **`:root`** que la etiqueta **`<html>`** en si misma

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [**Pseudoclase `:root`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#root-pseudo)
- <sup>2</sup> [Niveles de especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad)

Comment: Muchas gracias, al fin entiendo como usar rem y lo que significa root.

Answer (score 1):

`:root` es una pseudo clase que hace referencia a la raiz de una página, mientras que el selector `html` hace referencia a la etiqueta html de una página, esta etiqueta es la etiqueta base de una página asi que podemos decir que hacen referencia a lo mismo pero tienen diferencias de "especificidad", dicho de otra forma, tienen diferente "peso" a la hora de seleccionar con qué definición de estilo me quedo al usar uno u otro, ejemplos a continuación:

Usualmente cuando asignamos estilos css, el intérprete se queda con el último estilo que definimos. Por ejemplo tenemos dos objetos div de los cuales se les cambia a ambos en dos lugares sus estilos pero el intérprete se queda con la última definición

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
div 1
</div>


<div class="div2">
div 2
</div>
```

esto sin embargo no es igual para los selectores `:root` y `html` dado que `:root` tiene mas "peso", este no puede ser sobreescribido por el selector `html`

```css
html {
  background: red;
}

:root {
  background: blue;
}
```

no importa el orden...

```css
:root {
  background: blue;
}

html {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: para el caso de la propiedad `font-size:100%;`, debería asignarse con `:root{font-size:100%;}` ó con `html{font-size:100%;}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Hola te comento que :root y html significan lo mismo. Pero tienes una "especificidad diferente", :root "tiene mayor valor de especificidad", así que tenga en cuenta si seleccionamos elementos del DOM.